# How to install a feature in wso2 Carbon automatically?

Tags: wso2, api-manager

I'm trying to install 'Account Recovery and Credential Management' on my carbon automatically.

Currently, I'm installing this feature from the carbon UI with the following steps;

- login to Carbon as a super admin
- Navigate to Feature tab
- Add a repository
- Select 'Account Recovery and Credential Management' and install

However, I want to remove these steps and replace this step by some automatic such as placing appropriate jars in the right directory location.

I've try to place the following jars in repository/components/plugins;

- org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt_4.2.1.jar
- org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub_4.2.0.jar
- org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.ui_4.2.0.jar

It seems working apart from sending an email. When I'm trying to call

SendRecoveryNotification service, I'm getting this error;

```
ERROR - DefaultEmailSendingModule Failed Sending Emailnamed capturing group is missing trailing '}'
```

Is there any further steps I need to do as well or

Should I take completely different approach to achieve what I want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and pasting features is not recommended at all. When installing features there might be many files get updated, config files get added etc..
Therefore it is always better to use the UI based approach or you can use pom based approach. Youc an find more information regarding that by referring to https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon445/Installing+Features+using+pom+Files